# acessing data of a structure from another structure

Tags: c

Here src_addr is of type char[16], ptr->ip.ip_src.s_addr is used to access the source address of the packets that flows in the network when i assigned

```
keys.dst_addr =  ((ptr->ip.ip_dst.s_addr)&(0x0FF<<(i*8)))>>(i*8) ;
```

i used to get a error

error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[16]’ from type ‘in_addr_t’

so i assigned it in this form converted the source address using inet_ntoa is this the right way? i still get errors in this line

```
 keys.src_addr = inet_ntoa (ptr->ip.ip_src.s_addr);
```

Comment: Is Keys and ptr->ip of same type?

Comment: @gunner: key ia a structure, and ptr is a pointer to struct ip and member of the structure ip is  struct in_addr ip_src,ip_dst

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the definition of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
keys.dst_addr = inet_ntoa(ptr->ip.ip_dst);
keys.src_addr = inet_ntoa(ptr->ip.ip_src);
```